# Forgot to make child theme - can it be done now?

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I've added different things to my `functions.php`, and not in a child theme, so I can't update my theme.

Is it possible to just copy everything in my `functions.php`, make a child theme, and then paste in that `functions.php`? Or how is it done?

Comment: Id definetly mean thats possible. But why dont you just try it and see if it works?

Comment: Use something like this if you're not sure of what did you change: https://www.diffchecker.com/

Answer (score 0):

Yes it can be done, you can create a child theme and then in functions.php you can paste all your new functions.

Answer (score 0):

1. Suppose your parent theme folder(tweentyseventeen), create folder with name tweentyseventeen-child into your themes folder.
2. Add style.css file into child folder. Copy the commentted line from parent style.css to child style.css
   /*
   Theme Name:   Twenty Seveenten Child
   Theme URI:    http://example.com/twenty-seveenten-child/
   Description:  Twenty seveenten Child Theme
   Author:       John Doe
   Author URI:   http://example.com
   Template:     tweentyseventeen
   Version:      1.0.0
   License:      GNU General Public License v2 or later
   License URI:  http://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl-2.0.html
   Tags:         light, dark, two-columns, right-sidebar, responsive-layout, accessibility-ready
   Text Domain:  twenty-seventeen-child
   */
3. Add functions.php file into child folder and then add your code you want to add in.

Activate you child theme from backend.(apperances>theme)